# Slick2D: getTileProperty returns true when it shouldn't

Tags: java, collision-detection, slick2d

I'm trying to implement some collision detection to a test game i've been making.
I've used TiledMap to create the map and set a property on one of the tiles to blocked=true
This tile is then drawn on layer 0.

I then check to see if the tile exists in the direction the player is moving, using the following code

```
if (input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
    sprite = down;
    sprite.update(delta);
    int tileID = map.map.getTileId((int) x / map.map.getTileWidth(), (int) y / map.map.getTileHeight() + 1, 0);
    String value = map.map.getTileProperty(tileID, "blocked", "false");
    if (value.equals("true")) {
        y += delta * 0.1f;
        System.out.println("Tile ID: " + (int) (x / map.map.getTileWidth()) + ", " + (int) (y / map.map.getTileHeight() + 1) + " Try to walk down. Tile value below the player is:" + value);
    }

}
```

This is repeated for each direction.

The problem I'm running into is it's picking up the blocked property for incorrect tiles
You can understand better with [this video](http://youtu.be/FqEmjAbiKQU). The yellow tiles are the collision/blocked tiles.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where is the origin of your map?  Based on the video it looks like you may be checking the blocks behind you instead of in front of you (where you're adding 1 to your block, maybe you should be subtracting one).  The other thing I'd suggest is maybe figure out where your interpreting collision from.  Is x and y the middle of the top of the sprite or is it the center of the body?

Comment: map origin is always 0,0; that's not the question though.  Where is the origin being drawn?  Where is 0,0 on the drawn image?  Or more specifically, what quadrant are you working in?

Comment: The origin is in the top left.

Comment: Ok can you post the full code for your movement? All the if statements? I think I got a plausible answer, but I need to see that code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have this issue because you update the graphics outside your `if` statement

Try to move the ones below inside the `if`:

```
sprite = down; 
sprite.update(delta);
```

However I suppose one of these put the face of the sprite down and therefore should not be inside.

Comment: neither can be outside the if. The first because its what sets the sprites direction image, and the second if its outside the if the characters animation is always playing, not just when moving

Comment: can you please check value.equals("true") without "" so value.equals(true)